# Swift UITableView's data show in UIPickerView

Tags: uitableview, uipickerview

Hello I am a new beginning for programming,i have search a lot of article but no one can answer my issue so...help me

here is my question

I have already build UITableVIew and PickerView, and Using CoreDate now

I want to let UITableView's data show in UIPickerView(The data is all String)

how to load UITableView's Data put in UIPickerView?
"that two View is different View"

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement UIPickerViewDelegate methods in your picker class. And use this method from protocol for putting UITableView inside:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```